# When browsing for doc from iCloud Drive in iPhone some document are disabled

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, icloud

Build an App through provisioning profile, Which is iCloud enabled.
but when Access it,.doc and .xls file type is greyed out/disabled mode.

Am using following code to pick file from iCloud.

file_data = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();

Any help ?

Comment: Do you mean you can't open it or can't choose it?

Comment: i@LandLu-MSFT I can't choose it.Doc are in disabled mode